# Is there any way to get rid of my timeout countdown thread upon completing my sequence of inputs? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sequence

I am working on  a program where:

-we have a object detection loop

-it will be idle awaiting a user's input. Upon the first input, it will start a sequence of actions that need to be completed. If the user leaves and hasn't finished with the full sequence, I need to find a way to reset the sequence so that a new user can begin their own.

My current "solution" was to use a thread to start a timeout countdown by pointing the thread to the following function:

```
def timeout():
    count = 0
    t = 61
    while count <= 60:
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1
        t -= 1
        to_queue.put(t)
```

This function will start counting down 60 seconds, and putting the values through my queue `to_queue`.

After implementing this i realized it's not an optimal solution, due to the fact that if my user(A) finishes their sequence and another one(B) starts right away, the previous 60 seconds will still be counting and end the sequence too early for the second user(B), thus creating a possibly endless loop of unfinished sequences.

My criteria for "restarting" the sequence is in two locations: once it has been completed reset all the values, and the other is `if timeout == 0: reset sequence`

I have been looking through the documentation for Queue and Multithreading but I can't seem to find the right solution. I know that threads cannot be "killed" but I have run out of options from examples on how to "kill threads" online.

I also saw that theres `Timer()` under the threading library but I'm not sure how to implement it as it requires a function as its argument, but my hypothetical `restartSequence()` function would require resetting values located inside my `Sequence()` function.  I am stuck here and feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious. any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop, that while a new user input comes the function will keep counting. The moment a new user input comes, the function will stop.

Comment: Sorry i didn't make this clear in the original post:

the sequence() function has a while loop that will check for the start of the sequence(this is machine learning, so basically looping and detection awaiting the first step), so if i put another while loop inside it will freeze the rest of my code :S

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix my issue; I'm not sure how efficient this is but here goes:

I used an Event() object as a flag to run the "restart sequence" code:

```
from threading import Event
restartFlag = Event()

if restartFlag.set():
    restartSequence()
```

As for the countdown timer I gave up on using `Queue()`, and switched to using `Timer()`, which will execute a function when the set time runs out. `timeFlag` will run when the time reaches 0, restarting my sequence just like the queue used to. I realized that it was still running on the same timer upon starting a new sequence, so I created `newTimer()` to help me create a new Timer every time the sequence is started. It might not be the best option since I'm basically creating multiple threads for this, but they are supposed to die when finished, so there shouldn't be any problem AFAIK.

```
#Set resetFlag event in order to start Reset Sequence code
    def timeFlag():
        print("Reset Flag Set.")
        resetFlag.set()

    #Create new Timer() Object to avoid using the same every time
    def newTimer():
        print("Created new Reset Timer.")
        global resetTimer
        resetTimer = Timer(60.0, timeFlag)
    newTimer()
```

so then I do  `resetTimer.start()` when the sequence begins, and promptly use `resetTimer.cancel()` and `newTimer()` when the sequence is supposed to end.

Now we have a fully working sequence of steps